# Insert replacements into %-string subsequently

Tags: python

So I have the following:

```
myString = "This is %s string. It has %s replacements."
myParams = [ "some", "two" ]

# This is a function which works (and has to work) just like that
myFunction(myString, myParams)
```

Now when I debug, I do the following:

```
print("Debug: myString = " + myString)
print("Debug: myParams = " + myParams)
```

But I would like to get it all directly in one print, like:

```
"Debug: This is some string. It has two replacements."
```

Is that somehow possible? Something like

```
print("Debug: myString = " + (myString % myParams))
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a *tuple*; cast your list into a tuple and that works just fine:

```
>>> myString = "This is %s string. It has %s replacements."
>>> myParams = [ "some", "two" ]
>>> myString % tuple(myParams)
'This is some string. It has two replacements.'
```

Define `myParams` to be a tuple to start with:

```
>>> myString = "This is %s string. It has %s replacements."
>>> myParams = ("some", "two")
>>> myString % myParams
'This is some string. It has two replacements.'
```

You can combine that into a function:

```
def myFunction(myString, myParams):
    return myString % tuple(myParams)

myFunction("This is %s string. It has %s replacements.", ("some", "two"))
```

or better still, make `myParams` a catch-all argument, which always resolves to a tuple:

```
def myFunction(myString, *myParams):
    return myString % myParams

myFunction("This is %s string. It has %s replacements.", "some", "two")
```

The latter is what the `logging.log()` function (and related functions) already does.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Also thanks for the reference to `logging.log()`, didn't know that to date.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python 2.7 but this is quite close and tidy to what you're seeking

I am using the `*` or splat operator to unpack the list into positional arguments (or a tuple) and feeding that tuple into `format()` and using format on the `myString` variable is possible by changing the `%s` to `{index}`.

```
>> myString = "This is {0} string. It has {1} replacements."
>> myParams = ["some", "two"]
>> print "Debug: myString = "+ myString.format(*myParams)
>> Debug: myString = This is some string. It has two replacements.
```

Answer (score 0):

The most fundamental print syntax in achieving what you want is the following:

print "This is %s string. It has %s replacements." %("some", "two")

You may format it to be some sort of function (like what other people have replied you earlier), but I think there should be value in knowing the most basic print syntax.

%s in the string acts as a placeholder for the value stored inside the tuple.

You could have other placeholders such as floats (%f) and many more.

---

FYI, from Python 3 onwards, there is a newer (and cleaner) print format.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about. The new `str.format()` / `format()` option was added to Python 2.6 already, you don't have to wait until Python 3.

Comment: I thought it would be good to clarify.

Oh okay thanks for that correction regarding the str.format() option.